# Javascript code working in JSFiddle but not in my page

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

The code is copied from jsfiddle, but not working in my webpage. I tried to include the script at bottom and added document.ready function

code in JSfiddle

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/jW6eL/)

HTML

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>




       <form>
    <table border = "1" id = "engagements">
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)"></th>
            <th>Organization</th>
            <th>Project</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Activity</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)"></td>
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            <!--
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            <td><input type = "text"/></td>
            -->
        </tr>
    </table>

    <select name = "mode" id = "mode" onchange="addrow('engagements')">
        <option value="">Add More Rows with Same Data as Above</option>
        <option value="1">1 More</option>
        <option value="2">2 More</option>
        <option value="3">3 More</option>
        <option value="4">4 More</option>
        <option value="5">5 More</option>
     </select>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Error in webpage

newhtml.html:43 Uncaught ReferenceError: addrow is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (newhtml.html:43)

```
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
            $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#mode").on('change', function () {
    var rows = parseInt(this.value);
    var lastRow;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        lastRow = $('#engagements tr').last().clone();
        $('#engagements tr').last().after(lastRow);
    }
}); 
            }      
</script>
```

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You can't have `src` and content in single `<script>` tag.

Comment: From what I can tell, the error you get is normal, since you are calling an "addrow" method that you never actually define in your Javascript. Also, if you open up the console in your JSFiddle page, you will see that you get errors related to the non-existence of the method checkAll.

Comment: Thank you Justinas.. your suggestion helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#mode").on('change', function () {
var rows = parseInt(this.value);
var lastRow;
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    lastRow = $('#engagements tr').last().clone();
    $('#engagements tr').last().after(lastRow);
}
     }); 
           });


</script>
```

Comment: :) <3 @Javanewbie

Answer (score 0):

May be you didn't import jquery properly and you have added in same script tag as comment suggested

```js
$("#mode").on('change', function () {
    var rows = parseInt(this.value);
    console.log(rows);
    var lastRow;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        lastRow = $('#engagements tr').last().clone();
        $('#engagements tr').last().after(lastRow);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <table border="1" id="engagements">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)" />
            </th>
            <th>Organization</th>
            <th>Project</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Activity</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <select name="mode" id="mode">
        <option value="">Add More Rows with Same Data as Above</option>
        <option value="1">1 More</option>
        <option value="2">2 More</option>
        <option value="3">3 More</option>
        <option value="4">4 More</option>
        <option value="5">5 More</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When 'combo box' option is changed, you just declared to invoke function 'addrow' without definition.

Answer (score 0):

You must reference jquery in a separate script tag before you use it like this. Then add your code below it in an another script tag

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#mode").on('change', function () {
    var rows = parseInt(this.value);
    var lastRow;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        lastRow = $('#engagements tr').last().clone();
        $('#engagements tr').last().after(lastRow);
    }
}); 
            }      
</script>
```